# Calculating resistance by colors on the resistor

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int unos;
    char crna[20] = "crna";
    char braon[20] = "braon";
    char crvena[20] = "crvena";
    char narandzasta[20] ="narandzasta";
    char zuta[20] = "zuta";
    char zelena[20] = "zelena";
    char plava[20] = "plava";
    char ljubicasta[20] = "ljubicasta";
    char siva[20] = "siva";
    char bela[20] = "bela";
    char zlatna[20] = "zlatna";
    char srebrna[20] = "srebrna";

    puts("Unesite broj prstenova:");
    scanf("%i", &unos);

    if(unos == 5){

            int c1, c2, c3, m=0, t;
            char unos1[20] = "\0";
            int r;

            puts("Unesi boju 1. prstena:");
            scanf("%s",&unos1);

            if(strcmp(unos1, crna) == 0)
                c1 = 0;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, braon) == 0)
                c1 = 1;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, crvena) == 0)
                c1 = 2;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, narandzasta) == 0)
                c1 = 3;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, zuta) == 0)
                c1 = 4;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, zelena) == 0)
                c1 = 5;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, plava) == 0)
                c1 = 6;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, ljubicasta) == 0)
                c1 = 7;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, siva) == 0)
                c1 = 8;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, bela) == 0)
                c1 = 9;

            char unos2[20] = "\0";

            puts("Unesi boju 2. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", &unos2);

            if(strcmp(unos2, crna) == 0)
                c2 = 0;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, braon) == 0)
                c2 = 1;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, crvena) == 0)
                c2 = 2;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, narandzasta) == 0)
                c2 = 3;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, zuta) == 0)
                c2 = 4;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, zelena) == 0)
                c2 = 5;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, plava) == 0)
                c2 = 6;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, ljubicasta) == 0)
                c2 = 7;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, siva) == 0)
                c2 = 8;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, bela) == 0)
                c2 = 9;

            char unos3[20] = "\0";

            puts("Unesi boju 3. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", &unos3);

            if(strcmp(unos3, crna) == 0)
                c3 = 0;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, braon) == 0)
                c3 = 1;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, crvena) == 0)
                c3 = 2;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, narandzasta) == 0)
                c3 = 3;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, zuta) == 0)
                c3 = 4;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, zelena) == 0)
                c3 = 5;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, plava) == 0)
                c3 = 6;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, ljubicasta) == 0)
                c3 = 7;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, siva) == 0)
                c3 = 8;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, bela) == 0)
                c3 = 9;

            char mnoz[20] = "\0";
            puts("Unesi boju 4. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", &mnoz);

            if(strcmp(mnoz, crna) == 0)
                m = 1;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, braon))
                m = 10;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, crvena))
                m = 100;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, narandzasta))
                m = 1000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, zuta))
                m = 10000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, zelena))
                m = 100000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, plava))
                m = 1000000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, ljubicasta))
                m = 10000000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, siva))
                m = 100000000;
            //else if(strcmp(mnoz, bela))
                //m = 10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, zlatna))
                m = 0.1;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, srebrna))
                m = 0.01;

            r = ((c1*100)+(c2*10)+(c3*1)) * m;
            printf("%i,%i",m,r);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

So everything is ok, but the variable "m" is always 10 and if I enter "narandzasta" when it asks "Unesi boju 4. prstena:" it should be 1000. I can translate names of ints and chars to English if needed. I am a beginner in programming (we just started learning strings).

Comment: Don't use `&` for strings in scanf: `scanf("%s", mnoz);`

Comment: thank you, i will try this and will post the results.

Comment: nope, i removed & and its still the same.

Comment: You got lazy (or, more likely, careless): `if(strcmp(mnoz, crna) == 0)
                m = 1;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, braon))
                m = 10;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, crvena)) …` — the first one is correct, the rest are not.  Note that if you entered `braon`, you'd get `m == 100`.

Comment: Incidentally, if you know about structures, the code is crying out for the use of arrays of structures — and loops.  If you only know about arrays, you could probably improve the code with arrays and loops.

Comment: ooh shoot, its just im in a hurry its 11PM and i gotta finish this by tomorow, thank you so much. I know i can improve it but as i said im in a big hurry.

Comment: The color of the forth band is a 'tolerance', not a multiplier. AND you cannot put a 'double', like .1 into a int variable. When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for gcc, at a minimum use; `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to compare with 0 to see if the string is equal:

```
 if(strcmp(mnoz, crna) == 0)
            m = 1;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, braon) == 0)
            m = 10;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, crvena) == 0)
            m = 100;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, narandzasta) == 0)
            m = 1000;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, zuta)==0)
            m = 10000;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, zelena) == 0)
            m = 100000;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, plava) == 0)
            m = 1000000;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, ljubicasta) == 0)
            m = 10000000;
        else if(strcmp(mnoz, siva) == 0)
            m = 100000000;
```

And you declare m as int and in the final uses as double, your code corrected:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int unos;
    char crna[20] = "crna";
    char braon[20] = "braon";
    char crvena[20] = "crvena";
    char narandzasta[20] ="narandzasta";
    char zuta[20] = "zuta";
    char zelena[20] = "zelena";
    char plava[20] = "plava";
    char ljubicasta[20] = "ljubicasta";
    char siva[20] = "siva";
    char bela[20] = "bela";
    char zlatna[20] = "zlatna";
    char srebrna[20] = "srebrna";

    puts("Unesite broj prstenova:");
    scanf("%i", &unos);

    if(unos == 5){

            int c1, c2, c3, t;
            double m=0;
            char unos1[20] = "\0";
            int r;

            puts("Unesi boju 1. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", unos1);

            if(strcmp(unos1, crna) == 0)
                c1 = 0;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, braon) == 0)
                c1 = 1;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, crvena) == 0)
                c1 = 2;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, narandzasta) == 0)
                c1 = 3;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, zuta) == 0)
                c1 = 4;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, zelena) == 0)
                c1 = 5;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, plava) == 0)
                c1 = 6;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, ljubicasta) == 0)
                c1 = 7;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, siva) == 0)
                c1 = 8;
            else if(strcmp(unos1, bela) == 0)
                c1 = 9;

            char unos2[20] = "\0";

            puts("Unesi boju 2. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", unos2);

            if(strcmp(unos2, crna) == 0)
                c2 = 0;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, braon) == 0)
                c2 = 1;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, crvena) == 0)
                c2 = 2;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, narandzasta) == 0)
                c2 = 3;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, zuta) == 0)
                c2 = 4;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, zelena) == 0)
                c2 = 5;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, plava) == 0)
                c2 = 6;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, ljubicasta) == 0)
                c2 = 7;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, siva) == 0)
                c2 = 8;
            else if(strcmp(unos2, bela) == 0)
                c2 = 9;

            char unos3[20] = "\0";

            puts("Unesi boju 3. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", unos3);

            if(strcmp(unos3, crna) == 0)
                c3 = 0;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, braon) == 0)
                c3 = 1;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, crvena) == 0)
                c3 = 2;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, narandzasta) == 0)
                c3 = 3;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, zuta) == 0)
                c3 = 4;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, zelena) == 0)
                c3 = 5;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, plava) == 0)
                c3 = 6;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, ljubicasta) == 0)
                c3 = 7;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, siva) == 0)
                c3 = 8;
            else if(strcmp(unos3, bela) == 0)
                c3 = 9;

            char mnoz[20] = "\0";
            puts("Unesi boju 4. prstena:");
            scanf("%s", mnoz);

            if(strcmp(mnoz, crna) == 0)
                m = 1;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, braon) == 0)
                m = 10;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, crvena) == 0)
                m = 100;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, narandzasta) == 0)
                m = 1000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, zuta) == 0)
                m = 10000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, zelena) == 0)
                m = 100000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, plava) == 0)
                m = 1000000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, ljubicasta) == 0)
                m = 10000000;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, siva) == 0)
                m = 100000000;
            //else if(strcmp(mnoz, bela))
                //m = 10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, zlatna))
                m = 0.1;
            else if(strcmp(mnoz, srebrna))
                m = 0.01;

            r = ((c1*100)+(c2*10)+(c3*1)) * m;
            printf("%lf,%i",m,r);

    }

    return 0;

}
```